# How to parse apple music using python

Tags: python, parsing

```
def getLinks():
# Getting links
url = f"https://music.apple.com/ua/playlist/techno-essentials/pl.de1ac365ed3549698bcd6e099db5171d"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# applelinks = soup.find_all('meta', attrs = {"property":"music:song"})[0].get("content") #works but only with one link
# file.write(applelinks)
applelinks = soup.find_all('meta', attrs = {"property":"music:song"})
for link in enumerate(applelinks):
    file.write(link.get("content"))  #Objects has no attribute "get"
return
getLinks()
```

Im using Beautiful Soup and Requests libs. How can I get all links?

Comment: You don't need `enumerate` in the for loop as that would cause the `link` to be `tuple` (containing index and entry from `applelinks`). Without the `enumerate` there, your code for getting the `link.get("content")` would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Issue here is with the variable `link` being tuple which doesn't have attribute `get`. And why it's a `tuple` because `enumerate` is being used with the `for loop`.

```
enumerate(applelinks)
```

This returns a `enumerate object` which can be **iterable**. And each time in the `for loop` it would return a `tuple` with the `index` like below.

```
#input
for link in enumerate(applelinks):
   print(link)
```

```
#output
'index' 'applelinks object member'
 V        V
(0, <meta content="<link for the song>" property="music:song"/>)
(1, <meta content="<link for the song>" property="music:song"/>)
...
```

It's basically used when you need a `index` of object's member while iterating. Like below,

```
#input
for index, link in enumerate(applelinks):
    print(f'index of element: {index} | link: {link}')
```

```
#output
index of the element: 0 | link : <meta content="link for the song" property="music:song"/>
index of the element: 1 | link : <meta content="link for the song" property="music:song"/>
...
```

As the `index` is not required here, we can ditch the use of `enumerate` and iterate over the `applelinks` object.

```
#input
for link in applelinks:
    print(link.get("content"))
```

```
#output
song link
song link
...
```

**Note:** The links for the songs are being redacted as they are not required for the explanation.